# Rails 4 Windows 10 - undefined method assets - Rails::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

i installed Ruby 2.2.0 and rails on my windows 10 pc (yeah successfull :D). I also create my project (checkout from github) and install all gems.

My Problem now is that when i start the rails server i got following error message:

`Uncaught exception: undefined method 'assets' for #<Rails::Engine::Configuration:0x00000004f36318>`

Actually this checkout works on linux, so i think it must be a problem from windows/ruby/rails combination.

Maybe somebodys knows whats wrong. If you need more code, tell me.

Comment: You installed Ruby 2.2.0 on Windows without Nokogiri issues? What happens when you input `rails s`?

Comment: @RichPeck Haha well i dont have any issues. That surprise me...see my pastebin for what happens when i execute rails s 
http://pastebin.com/s3UMucvy

Comment: @RichPeck But now you say it i remember the following: i create a new rails app (for testing) and there came the message "nokogiri not installed" I dont know why it dont came in this project

Comment: Wow this is interesting. Can you create a new rails app and confirm that it runs? I've got Win10 and just battling through a bunch of issues which you may have

Comment: @RichPeck Ok. After creating a new rails app (rails new blog) and install nokogiri i can normally start the server. Everythings fine with the new app

Comment: Wow this is rare for Win + Ruby 2.2.0 :) So the error does look like its with assets -- what's the engine you're calling, or is it in the rails core?

Comment: @RichPeck Rails core i think ;) Didnt change anything..just write my code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works now...It sounds strange but after i checkout my project again, i only had some issues with sqlite3. But now it works. No engine error anymore. 
I know that this is not a fix for the problem, but it helped me.